# Outer join and self-refer in Oracle

Tags: oracle, outer-join, self-join

I have customers with contract at various sites which must be charged.

There are two types of billing address for the sites: sites charged at the customer's address and sites charged to another address.
The kind of site is handled by the field 'status': if the site is charged at the customer's address, the field is equal to 'C'. If it is charged to a different site's address, it is equal to 'A' and the field 'bill_site_id' is filled with the 'site_id' used for billing. I want to retrieve, in one query, the address where I have to send the bill...

Let's say a customer have two sites (the A refers to the B for billing); the request obviously shows the two sites, but I only want the one used for billing (the B).
How to retrieve this one only?

Here is my query (anonymized, so please be  gentle :-) )

```
SELECT CASE wp.status
      WHEN 'A'
         THEN wp2.name
      ELSE c.NAME
   END AS NAME,
   CASE wp.status
      WHEN 'A'
         THEN wp2.adress
      ELSE c.street
   END AS street,
   CASE wp.status
      WHEN 'A'
         THEN wp2.city
      ELSE c.city
   END AS city,
   CASE wp.status
      WHEN 'A'
         THEN wp2.postcode
      ELSE c.postcode
   END AS postcode
FROM customer c, site wp, site wp2, customer_site cwp
WHERE c.idcompany = cwp.idcompany
    AND cwp.site_id = wp.site_id
    AND wp2.site_id(+) = wp.bill_site_id
    AND c.idcompany = :someId
GROUP BY wp.status,
     wp2.name,
     wp2.adress,
     wp2.city,
     wp2.postcode
```

Comment: The `(+) =` syntax is so old. There are `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins in Oracle, years now.

Comment: Yeah, but old style syntax is used everywhere in my application, I don't want to change the way everyone do this... anyway, I already tried a simple left join and the result is the same.

Comment: what table is "ch" aliased to?

Comment: Okay, I'm totally confused with this question.  Like, what does "(the A refers to the B for billing)" mean?  And why do you have the table "site" twice in the FROM clause?

Comment: The table 'site' can't self-refer to itself. Or Oracle is a liar, because it forbid me to do so; I must add this table twice to get the billing address.

Comment: The old syntax can actually cause problems. I've found cases where the query optimizer doesn't handle it the same way as it handles the explicit JOIN syntax. Maybe it doesn't matter in this case, but I basically forbade its use around the office now.

Comment: I already tried that, but no changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I know what you want but am not 100% sure what 'ch.status' refers to in the query. Also i am not sure that from the information given you can achieve what you want ...

Hopefully the data structures are under your control so you can set it up how you want.

If I read your specification correctly then I think you want/need only 1 instance of the site table in the query, but it is then not clear how you identify the customer's address.

One way round this is for the site table to have an main_address flag.  (I think this is the confusion around ch.status)

If there is a flag on the site table then ...

WHERE c.idcompany = cwp.idcompany
    AND cwp.site_id = wp.site_id
    AND (
          (C.STATUS = 'C' AND WP.MAIN_ADDRESS = 1) OR
          (C.STATUS = 'A' AND WP.SITE_ID = C.BILL_SITE_ID)
        )

Another way would be to have the Main Adress and Billing addresses as foreign keys on the customer table, and to forget about the status flag so :

WHERE WP.SITE_ID = DECODE(C.BILLING_ADDRESS, NULL, C.MAIN_ADDRESS, C.BILLING_ADDRESS)

If this makes no sense then perhaps you can post a DESCRIBE of the tables involved.

Comment: This could have help but the flag is on the 'site' table only, and I can't change the table structure... I'll try to post an anonymized description of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Technically a Union is two queries, but you can run it in a single command and it should do what you want so I'm throwing it out as an option. :)

```
SELECT c.Name AS NAME, c.street AS STREET, c.city AS CITY, c.postcode AS postcode
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_site cwp ON c.idcompany = cwp.idcompany
INNER JOIN site wp ON cwp.site_id = wp.site_id
WHERE c.idcompany = :someid AND wp.status = 'C'
UNION
SELECT wp2.name AS NAME, wp2.adress AS STREET, wp2.city AS CITY, wp2.postcode AS postcode
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_site cwp ON c.idcompany = cwp.idcompany
INNER JOIN site wp ON cwp.site_id = wp.site_id
INNER JOIN site wp2 ON wp.bill_site_id = wp2.site_id
WHERE c.idcompany = :someid AND wp.status = 'A'
```

I can't see your table structure so it's probably possible to optimize more, but I think that'll help point you in a working direction. This may very well not be any faster then your existing query, but it's a fair bit easier to understand.